# ES6: Can a getter inherit from a parent if the child overrides the setter?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I'm using a getter/setter in a parent class. As expected, I can use the getter/setter in child class (see Bar0 below). I want to override the setter in a child class. I thought the getter function would inherit but it won't (see Bar1 below). Do I have to duplicate the getter for each child class where I want to edit the setter (like Bar2 below)?

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(){
    this._test;
  }
  get test(){
    return this._test;
  }
  set test(val){
    this._test = "Foo "+val;
  }
}
class Bar1 extends Foo{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  // omit get test(), want to inherit from parent
  set test(val){
    this._test = "Bar "+val;
  }
}
class Bar0 extends Foo{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}
class Bar2 extends Foo{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  get test(){ // <-- redundant, copied from parent
    return this._test;
  }
  set test(val){
    this._test = "Bar "+val;
  }
}

var bar0 = new Bar0();
var bar1 = new Bar1();
var bar2 = new Bar2();

bar0.test = "Test!";
bar1.test = "Test!";
bar2.test = "Test!";

console.log(bar0.test);
console.log(bar1.test);
console.log(bar2.test);
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt if that's possible. You're defining a property on the child, so that should stop the prototype chain traversal at that point.